# Unable to find valid certification path, jboss 5.1.0

Tags: java, soap, cmd, ssl-certificate, jboss5.x

When I am trying to invoke a SOAP webservice (.wsdl) that needs basic authentication over `HTTPS` from my local environment, I got the SSLHandShakeException.

First I have downloaded the certificate `Cert.cer` from the Chrome browser and followed the below steps.

```
1) keytool -genkey -dname "CN=localhost:8080, OU=Group Name, O=Company Name,L=City Name, S=State, C=IN" -alias "key_alias" -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -keystore server.keystore 

2) copy server.keystore C:\Work\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf

3) keytool -export -alias "key_alias" -file Cert.cer -keystore C:\Work\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\server.keystore

4) copy Cert.cer C:\Work\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf

5) keytool -printcert -v -file C:\Work\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\Cert.cer

6) keytool -import -alias "key_alias" -file Cert.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

### In C:\Work\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml

```
<!-- SSL/TLS Connector configuration using the admin devl guide keystore-->
  <Connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}" keyAlias="key_alias"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
       keystoreFile="C:\Work\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\server.keystore"
       keystorePass="changeit" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

After followed these steps, still I am facing the same exception as `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

```
2013-12-04 12:31:14,841 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8443-6) AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode: 
faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: 
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

what was the wrong in that? Could anyone helps me to find that??

Comment: this exception comes when you have specified wrong path to trust store and your application does not find valid key/trust store

Comment: where we can find that wrong path to trust store and how, is there any command for that...???

Comment: I am able to see the certificate, what i have imported into the keystore, in the list of certificates in `cacerts` file of /security folder through command prompt.